# XFCE logs me out immediately instead of asking

Tags: arch-linux, xfce, logout

Normally, 'log out' in XFCE was opening a window and offered "log out", "shutdown" and other options.

Now it logs me out immediately and I don't know why. How could I find out why this is happening (and change it) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stupid mistake.

I had the setting "*vor dem abmelden fragen/ ask before logging out*" not set in *Settings --> Session (Einstellungen --> Sitzung und Startverhalten)*.

Checked the checkbox and it works again as expected.